# C# Best way to share logic and re-use code

Tags: c#, code-reuse

The given function returns a KPI value, first it checks its cache, then it performs its logic, caches the result and returns a value, handling a failure condition.

How am I best to re-use the caching, error handling logic. What I essentially want to create is a function that just performs the necessary logic with boiler plate code abstracted away and re-used across multiple similar functions.

```
public static int CurrentEmployees()
 {
     if (HttpRuntime.Cache["CurrentEmployees"] == null)
     {
         try
         {
             int CurrentEmployees = Employee.Load().Count(x => x.DateFinished == null && !x.Contractor && x.DateStarted < DateTime.Now);
             HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert("CurrentEmployees", CurrentEmployees, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20), new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0));

             return CurrentEmployees;
         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
             //TODO: Report this
             return -1;
         }
     }
     else
         return (int)HttpRuntime.Cache["CurrentEmployees"];
 }
```

As the boilerplate code is wrapped around the logic it is difficult for me to simply push these into other function calls.

Comment: The common part can go into a separate method (sometimes generic), the individual part either passed as parameters into or delegated, or post-executed (after method call). How does another function looks like? The assigning new value (in case it is missing) can be delegated and added with lamda, while name is passed as a parameter.

Comment: Seems to me that you should probably use [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29). That is a broad topic though.. And depends on your setup. Could you explain what you have tried and why that did not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you could create a generic method to cache whatever you want and reuse this logic.

```
public static T Cache<T>(string key, Func<T> loadFunction, Func<T> errorHandler)
{
     if (HttpRuntime.Cache[key] == null)
     {
         try
         {
             T value = loadFunction();
         HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(key, value , null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20), new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0));
             return value;
         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
             //TODO: Report this
             return errorHandler();
         }
     }
     else
         return (T)HttpRuntime.Cache[key];
}
```

Usage:

```
public static int CurrentEmployees()
{
    return Cache<int>("CurrentEmployees", 
        () => Employee.Load().Count(x => x.DateFinished == null && !x.Contractor && x.DateStarted < DateTime.Now),
        () => -1);
}
```

Comment: you can add same kind of generic helper for exception handling, accepting function to call on exception as first argument and real function as the second argument. Then use it to wrap function passed to Cache wrapper. This way cache will not have error handling logic.

Comment: not sure what you mean. feel free to post your own answer to show what you mean.

Comment: well I agree with your answer, it is just that Cache in your example has two responsibilities - caching and error handling, and you can rewrite it to follow "single responsibility". Something like this: `return Cache<int>("CurrentEmployees", () => Error<int>(()=> -1, () => Employee.Load()));
}`

Comment: IMHO, be careful with these kind of solutions (i.e. passing functions as arguments) - they tend to grow and are harder to maintain then, for instance, abstract base classes and derived methods.

Comment: I don't really agree with that. In this case, at least, it's a `static` method, so it won't be affected by inheritance

Comment: added my version to explain what I meant

Answer (score 0):

Agree with [answer from @DLeh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31341738/4910910) but I would write it like this:

```
public static class HelperFunctions
{
    public static Func<T> Cache<T>(this Func<T> inner, string cacheName)
    {
        return () =>
        {
            if (HttpRuntime.Cache[cacheName] == null)
            {
                var result = inner();
                HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(cacheName, inner(), null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20), new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0));

                return result;
            }

            return (T)HttpRuntime.Cache[cacheName];
        };
    }

    public static Func<T> OnError<T>(this Func<T> inner, Func<Exception, T> onError)
    {
        return () =>
        {
            try
            {
                return inner();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return onError(e);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public static class Employees
{
    public static int CurrentEmployees()
    {
        return (new Func<int>(() => Employee.Load().Count(x => x.DateFinished == null && !x.Contractor && x.DateStarted < DateTime.Now)))
            .Cache("CurrentEmployees")
            .OnError(e => -1) 
            ();//TODO: log?
    }
}
```

This way we separate caching logic from error handling (following single responsibility principle) and are able to reuse/compose each separately. So when you add another function like this you won't have to change Caching function.